# How to specify FieldDescriptors for a nested order object for Spring RestDocs i.e. MockMvc

Tags: rest, spring-mvc

I have a nested structure for which I want to generate a RestDoc with Spring MockMvc. I have a problem specifying the nested structure.  Here is what I have so far which works without specifying the nested object.

```
Customer c = new Customer("John", 30);
Order order = new Order(....);
c.addOrder(order);

{
 "name":"John",
 "age":30,
 "orders": {
 "orderNumber":"12345",
  "quantity":"1",
  "productCode":"CDE-112",
  "productName" :"bicycle"     
}



 ResultActions resultActions = mockMvc.perform(get("/orders/user/{customerId}" ,

 "001022207")
             .contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE))
            .andExpect(status().isOk()).andDo(document("getProductsForUser" ,
                    preprocessRequest(prettyPrint()) ,
                    preprocessResponse(prettyPrint()) ,
                    responseFields(
                            fieldWithPath("name").type(JsonFieldType.STRING).description("The customer name"),
                            fieldWithPath("age").type(JsonFieldType.NUMBER).description("The age of the customer.") ,
```

Unfortunately, I have no idea how to include the nested order for the customer.

I would really appreciate it if someone could help me figure out how to include the field descriptors for the nested order.

Answer (score -1):

Here is how I solved it:

```
ResultActions resultActions = mockMvc.perform(get("/orders/user/{customerId}","001022207")
        .contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE))
        .andExpect(status().isOk()).andDo(document("getProductsForUser" ,
                preprocessRequest(prettyPrint()) ,
                preprocessResponse(prettyPrint()) ,
                responseFields(         
      fieldWithPath("name").type(JsonFieldType.STRING).description("The customer name"),                            
      fieldWithPath("age").type(JsonFieldType.NUMBER).description("The age of the customer."),
      fieldWithPath("orders.[].orderNumber").description("The ordernumber"),
      fieldWithPath("orders.[].quantity").description("quantity ordered")
```

etc...